# Reading Outlook emails from another address with win32com [using python]

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I'm trying to read emails from outlook address using win32com, but I can only access the items from local outlook address. Do you know how to input the needed credentials for another address?
In my Dispatch() method accepts username parameter but no password.

Here is my approach:

```
import win32com.client
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application", userName='marius.anton@cgi.com').GetNamespace("MAPI")
        for account in outlook.Session.Accounts:
        print (account.DisplayName) # robert.farcas@cgi.com
        print (account.SmtpAddress)
                print (account.UserName)
                print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
                dir(win32com.client.Dispatch)
                help(win32com.client.Dispatch)
                print(outlook.Session.Accounts.GetIDsOfNames)
```

And my output from the console:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use the [NameSpace.Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon) method which logs the user on to MAPI, obtaining a MAPI session. Use the `Logon` method only to log on to a specific profile when Outlook is not already running. This is because only one Outlook process can run at a time, and that Outlook process uses only one profile and supports only one MAPI session. When users start Outlook a second time, that instance of Outlook runs within the same Outlook process, does not create a new process, and uses the same profile.

Also you may find the [NameSpace.GetGlobalAddressList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getglobaladdresslist) method helpful which returns an `AddressList` object that represents the Exchange Global Address List. `GetGlobalAddressList` supports only Exchange servers. It returns an error if the Global Address List is not available or cannot be found.

You can use the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile. A profile defines one or more email accounts, and each email account is associated with a server of a specific type. For an Exchange server, a store can be on the server, in an Exchange Public folder, or in a local Personal Folders File (.pst) or Offline Folder File (.ost). For a POP3, IMAP, or HTTP email server, a store is a .pst file. Use the `Stores` and `Store` objects to enumerate all folders and search folders on all stores in the current session.

If you need to get accounts not configured in Outlook, but shared ones. The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` folder).

Comment: Tried to use ```Logon```. But didn't got the expected result. What I'm missing. Attached the code here.
```outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
out = outlook.Logon("autoenquirytest@robo.com",'', True, True)
wich_accnt = out.Folders
#try the restrict method!
for i in wich_accnt:
    print(i.Name)```

Comment: It seems you have already changed the original post with another problem. I'd recommend posting new questions in new threads, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right to open the other user's mailbox/folders, you can use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient, olFolderInbox)` (where `Recipient` object can be created using `Namespace.CreateRecipient`).

If you need the entire mailbox, not just one of the default folders, the mailbox should be added to the list of stores in the current profile either automatically (Outlook automatically adds accessible delegate stores available to the current user based on the information in autodiscover XML) or manually in the Exchange account setting dialog (Advanced | Open these additional mailboxes). In that case, `Namespace.Stores` collection will contain all mailboxes visible in the current session and you will be able to access all folder starting with the `Store.GetRootFolder()`. If the store is not in the list, you can try to use [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemptio) (I am its author) - it exposes [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetSharedMailbox` method.